# What does "specify multiple search patterns" by `-e` in grep mean?

Tags: grep

From grep's manual

> ```
> ‘-e pattern’
> ‘--regexp=pattern’
> ```
>
> This can be used to **specify multiple
>   search patterns**, or to protect a pattern beginning with a ‘-’. (‘-e’
>   is specifi ed by POSIX.)

What does "specify multiple search patterns" mean?

Does it mean exactly to output each line which contains all the search patterns specified by `-e`? If yes, does it do the same thing as piping multiple greps, each of which matches one of the patterns?

Thanks.

Comment: Works just as or operator. Especially usefull in case of patterns starting with dash (i.e man awk |grep C10 -e "-F" -e "OFS"

Answer (score 3):

To clarify the existing comments and answer: no, it doesn't work the way the OP described.

In fact:

```
grep -e foo -e bar -e baz myfile
```

prints out the lines containing **either** `foo` **or** `bar` **or** `baz`.

```
grep foo myfile | grep bar | grep baz
```

prints out the lines containing `foo` **and** `bar` **and** `baz` (not necessarily in this order).

Comment: Your second command line should read `grep foo myfile | grep bar | grep baz`, otherwise, its output would be the one of `grep baz myfile` as grep ignores its stdin when one or more file names are provided as arguments.

Comment: @jiliagre Oops. Good catch. Fixed, and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't mean the patterns are ANDed together.

What it means is that you can specify multiple patterns, without the second and subsequent patterns being interpreted as filenames.

Consider the following:

```
grep pattern1 file1
```

Simple enough.  Now consider:

```
grep pattern1 file1 file2
```

And:

```
# This doesn't work
grep pattern1 pattern2 file1 file2
# But this does.  There's no difference that's obvious to a computer.
grep pattern1 file1 file2 file3
```

Do you see the problem?

But, with `-e`, you can do:

```
grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the POSIX grep description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html):

> By default, an input line shall be selected if any pattern [...]
>   matches any part of the line excluding the terminating `<newline>`.

Comment: Translation: multiple patterns are `OR`-ed together, while piping multiple `grep`s means `AND`-ing together the corresponding patterns.