# How would I implement alternation with regex (Basic Regular Expressions only) in grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, posix

I am aware that this question does not make much sense, since I could just use Extended Regular Expressions (ERE). But let's say for a minute, that implementing alternation is the only option right now. How would I implement it only with BRE? Or would I have to find a workaround instead?

Let's say we have this string:

```
AAAAAA======-----======AAAAAAAAA
```

My goal now is to match AAAAA, ======, -----, ====== and AAAAAAAAA separately only with Basic Regular Expressions. With ERE this would be quickly done, but I would like to know how one would implement it only via BRE. So far, I couldn't find a proper way to do it without having some of the strings being matched overlapping into eachother (like regex matching "AAAAA==" which shouldn't happen).

Comment: What would be the ERE that will match as you ask?

Comment: Possibly related: [What does “specify multiple search patterns” by `-e` in grep mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345361/what-does-specify-multiple-search-patterns-by-e-in-grep-mean)

Comment: @Isaac The ERE version would be: `( [A]{1,} ) | ( [=]{1,} ) | ( [-]{1,} )`

Comment: Then: As there is no alternation (`|`) in BRE it is simply impossible to build a BRE regex that does the same. You can use other grep capabilities or seek a workaround, but an equivalent BRE is **not** possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: It is [**not** possible for an BRE to have *alternation*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)

> POSIX BRE does not support any other features. Even alternation is not supported.

Your basic goal:

> My goal now is to match ... separately ... with Basic Regular Expressions.

Is possible with BRE:

```
$ str='AAAAAA======-----======AAAAAAAAA'
$ echo "$str" | grep -Eo '(.)\1*'
AAAAAA
======
-----
======
AAAAAAAAA
```

Or even with several patterns in BRE grep:

```
$ echo "$str" | grep -o -e 'AA*' -e '--*' -e '==*'
AAAAAA
======
-----
======
AAAAAAAAA
```

Or restrict your solution to GNU grep (allows `\|` as alternation even in BRE syntax; which is not a valid POSIX feature):

```
$ echo "$str" | grep -o '\(AA*\)\|\(==*\)\|\(--*\)'
```

But your secondary goal:

> is it also possible to additionally put them in separate capture groups as well?

Calls for only **one** regex, and as it is not possible to have alternation in BRE, that is not possible.

[A very good explanation about alternation in BRE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/62944/can-posix-bre-express-all-regular-languages)

Answer (score 1):

To match strings of repeated characters with *basic regular expressions*:

```
$ echo 'AAAAAA======-----======AAAAAAAAA' | grep -o '\(.\)\1*'
AAAAAA
======
-----
======
AAAAAAAAA
```

`.` matches any character.  `\(.\)` matches any character and stores that character in capture group 1.  `\1*` matches any additional occurrences of that same character.

The use of back-references, like `\1`, in BRE is supported by  [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).

Comment: I see. So, is it also possible to additionally put them in separate capture groups as well?

Comment: @Caje Yes, that's possible, although it is not at all clear to me how one would benefit from doing that.  What is it, _exactly_, that you want to accomplish?